# Getting new permission dialog related to Network and Package list permissions in Android 14

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Thanks for in advance.
This issue is related to Android 14 and above versions. I am getting a new permission dialog while start the application. You can see this dialog in attachment below.
I want to handle the event when click on **Okay** and **Cancel** button.
I tried to investigate about this but didn't get any solution.So, help me to resolve this issue.

Thank you all.

[image]

I tried to handle System Dialog using runtime permission as given below link

https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting#kotlin

Comment: Why do you want to do that? You can use [checkSelfPermission](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#checkSelfPermission(java.lang.String)) to check for the grant status of each permissions. Clicking "OK" or "Cancel" in the dialog means NOTHING about the permission status.

Comment: Thanks ricky-mo. There are some logic in the Application class, so i want to execute this logic after user click on Okay button that's why i want the click event of Okay and Cancel button.